# How do I create a Sidebar which scrolls with the main content using tailwind.css?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

How do I create a Sidebar which scrolls with the main content using tailwind.css ?

Here is the code I have so far: (Please excuse the untidyness of the code I cut the pages content out and am not very good at indenting the code properly. If you have any other suggestions regarding the sidebar, please let me know.) If you need the rest of the Code I will glady provide further code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


    <!-- NavBar !-->
    <nav class="bg-blue-400 border-gray-200 px-2 sm:px-4 py-2.5 rounded dark:bg-gray-900">
        <div class="container flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center mx-auto">
          <a href="# class="flex items-center">
              <img/>
              <span class="self-center text-xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white"></span>
          </a>
          <button data-collapse-toggle="navbar-default" type="button" class="inline-flex items-center p-2 ml-3 text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" aria-controls="navbar-default" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
            <svg class="w-6 h-6" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
          </button>
          <div class="hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto" id="navbar-default">
            <ul class="flex flex-col mt-4 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:mt-0 md:text-sm md:font-medium">
              <li>
                <a href="index.html" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-white bg-blue-700 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white" aria-current="page">Azubi-Wiki</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="lernmaterial.html" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 border-b border-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-50 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Lernmaterial</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ticketbearbeitung.html" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 border-b border-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-50 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Ticketbearbeitung</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="taiwan.html" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 border-b border-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-50 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Taiwan Escalation</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="phraseexpress.html" class="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Phrase Express</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>


      <!-- Sidebar + Text !-->
<div class="flex flex-row space-x-10">
    <div class="flex flex-1 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="w-64 sticky bg-gray-200 p-4">
            <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col">
            <ul class="space-y-2">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4M7.835 4.697a3.42 3.42 0 001.946-.806 3.42 3.42 0 014.438 0 3.42 3.42 0 001.946.806 3.42 3.42 0 013.138 3.138 3.42 3.42 0 00.806 1.946 3.42 3.42 0 010 4.438 3.42 3.42 0 00-.806 1.946 3.42 3.42 0 01-3.138 3.138 3.42 3.42 0 00-1.946.806 3.42 3.42 0 01-4.438 0 3.42 3.42 0 00-1.946-.806 3.42 3.42 0 01-3.138-3.138 3.42 3.42 0 00-.806-1.946 3.42 3.42 0 010-4.438 3.42 3.42 0 00.806-1.946 3.42 3.42 0 013.138-3.138z" />
                      </svg>
                        <span class="ml-3">Example</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M9 5H7a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2h10a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2M9 5a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2M9 5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2m-6 9l2 2 4-4" />
                      </svg>
                        <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Example</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M14 10l-2 1m0 0l-2-1m2 1v2.5M20 7l-2 1m2-1l-2-1m2 1v2.5M14 4l-2-1-2 1M4 7l2-1M4 7l2 1M4 7v2.5M12 21l-2-1m2 1l2-1m-2 1v-2.5M6 18l-2-1v-2.5M18 18l2-1v-2.5" />
                      </svg>
                        <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Example</span> 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M10 21h7a2 2 0 002-2V9.414a1 1 0 00-.293-.707l-5.414-5.414A1 1 0 0012.586 3H7a2 2 0 00-2 2v11m0 5l4.879-4.879m0 0a3 3 0 104.243-4.242 3 3 0 00-4.243 4.242z" />
                    </svg>
                      <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Example</span> 
                  </a>
              </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M21 12a9 9 0 01-9 9m9-9a9 9 0 00-9-9m9 9H3m9 9a9 9 0 01-9-9m9 9c1.657 0 3-4.03 3-9s-1.343-9-3-9m0 18c-1.657 0-3-4.03-3-9s1.343-9 3-9m-9 9a9 9 0 019-9" />
                      </svg>
                        <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Example</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4 7v10c0 2.21 3.582 4 8 4s8-1.79 8-4V7M4 7c0 2.21 3.582 4 8 4s8-1.79 8-4M4 7c0-2.21 3.582-4 8-4s8 1.79 8 4m0 5c0 2.21-3.582 4-8 4s-8-1.79-8-4" />
                      </svg>
                        <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Example</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 5v2m0 4v2m0 4v2M5 5a2 2 0 00-2 2v3a2 2 0 110 4v3a2 2 0 002 2h14a2 2 0 002-2v-3a2 2 0 110-4V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5z" />
                      </svg>
                        <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Example</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M8 12h.01M12 12h.01M16 12h.01M21 12c0 4.418-4.03 8-9 8a9.863 9.863 0 01-4.255-.949L3 20l1.395-3.72C3.512 15.042 3 13.574 3 12c0-4.418 4.03-8 9-8s9 3.582 9 8z" />
                    </svg>
                      <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Example</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7 8h10M7 12h4m1 8l-4-4H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V6a2 2 0 012-2h14a2 2 0 012 2v8a2 2 0 01-2 2h-3l-4 4z" />
                  </svg>
                    <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Example</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M17 16l4-4m0 0l-4-4m4 4H7m6 4v1a3 3 0 01-3 3H6a3 3 0 01-3-3V7a3 3 0 013-3h4a3 3 0 013 3v1" />
                </svg>
                  <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Example</span>
              </a>
          </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav> 
    </div>
    <div class="static-row space-y-20 p-3">
        <div id="Einleitung">
            <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
            <p>
              
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Abgleich">
            <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
            <p>
            
              </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Thema Eingrenzen">
          <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
          <p>
            
          </p>
          <p>
            
           </p>
            <img>
      </div>
        <div id="GatherInformation">
            <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
            <p>
              
            </p>
            <p>
             
            </p>
      </div>

        <div id="GIDF">
          <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
          <p>
           
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="KIKB">
        <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
        <p>
          
        </p>
      </div>

      <div id="Ticketabgleich">
        <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
          <p>
            
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="Kollegen">
        <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
          <p>
             
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="Cowork">
        <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
          <p>
          
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="Eskalation">
        <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-5xl mt-0 mb-2 text-blue-600 padding: ">Example</h1>
          <p>
          
          </p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-direction: bottom-0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sticky if there is an overflow-hidden in the parent somewhere.
I've fixed it check this out: [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/01VpCQi7MF?size=1724x876)

I've made changes around line 35 to 40